# Something like a UX 'checklist' for designing elements for beginners?

Tags: ux-designer, style-guide

We (more experienced designers) have a few noobies at work and were wondering if there isn't something like a general checklist for them to go through, e.g. when they're designing an element for a website, so we can make sure they at least got the very basics covered.
(They didn't have extensive UX education and some are career jumpers)

And it is not possible to let them test their designs with real users, it's simply a matter of money & time. Unfortunate, but that's why we were wondering if we couldn't at least give them something to hold on to when doing their practices or first designs. This way they wouldn't have to stop their & an experienced colleague's work just to ask very basic questions.

This may sound like we don't want to teach them, but it is simply about making the process a little bit easier and actually make their questions be worth the time.

Anyone had experiences with that?

**EDIT:** Maybe a better question would be: How would I go about creating such a guide / checklist for them to follow, which is easy and specific enough to apply in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this article on UX Planet quite helpful, and there are probably others like this where they expand on the 10 Heuristics of design to create common things to look out for under each of the points.

https://uxplanet.org/a-new-usability-heuristic-evaluation-checklist-259f588da308

The author includes a link to a Google Sheet that they shared so you can probably go over it and modify some of the items to suit the product or service you are trying to design.

Comment: Yoooo that Google Sheet thing is super cool, I think that might be just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

https://uxdesign.cc/10-usability-heuristics-every-designer-should-know-129b9779ac53

The 10 Heuristics which Nielsen publicised, but which I think pre-date him.

Comment: I understand that this would be a good _general_ start for someone learning UX, but I'm afraid it's too general and thus too hard for them to apply to specific elements or components. That is why I was left wondering if there may be something like that, but I guess I could be looking in vain.

Comment: Well, if you want something specific, there are things like the 113 design guidelines for home page usability (https://www.nngroup.com/articles/113-design-guidelines-homepage-usability/) but that might just make the design process too long. I suggest making sure that they understand the basics before getting into the details.

Comment: For a longer read the late 80s Apple (Mac) Interface Design Guidelines, start with the general principles of interface design.

Answer (score 1):

This one is super comprehensive - I personally grew it bit by bit and use it with my students
https://pencilandpaper.io/articles/user-experience/interaction-design-checklist/